# View scroll when keyboard open for typing in Entry Control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms.labs

when user focus Entry Control in Xamarin.Form keyboard open but view scroll so Design looks ugly.so please help me.
i have put image how screen visible when keyboard open in android device.
My code given below

```
<StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <StackLayout Padding="20,10,20,20" >
            <Entry x:Name="Txtusername" Placeholder="Name"/>
            <Entry x:Name="TxtPass"
                   IsPassword="True"
                   Placeholder="Password" />
            <StackLayout Padding="0,10">
                <Button x:Name="BtnSign"
                        BackgroundColor="#FFFFCB04"
                        BorderColor="#FFFFCB04"
                        Clicked="BtnSignInClicked"
                        Text="Sign In"
                        TextColor="Black" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
```

[Before keyboard open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jamH7.png)

[After keyboard open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rasiv.png)

Comment: have you tried doing this layout with just Grids? XF layout still feels kind of public beta like. Picking a different layout control sometimes fixes issues.

Answer (score 0):

Add `WindowSoftInputMode=SoftInput.AdjustPan` in your `[Activity()]` on top of your MainActivity class from where the FormsApplication start.

This is so that your layout does not change when keyboard is active. I think you won't need scroll here. If you want scroll then add scroll view in your code

```
<ScrollView>
.//your grid 
.
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="1">
        <StackLayout Padding="20,10,20,20" >
            <Entry x:Name="Txtusername" Placeholder="Name"/>
            <Entry x:Name="TxtPass"
                   IsPassword="True"
                   Placeholder="Password" />
            <StackLayout Padding="0,10">
                <Button x:Name="BtnSign"
                        BackgroundColor="#FFFFCB04"
                        BorderColor="#FFFFCB04"
                        Clicked="BtnSignInClicked"
                        Text="Sign In"
                        TextColor="Black" />
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```